# Sql query to show all column values as a single statement adding some strings related to each other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have EMP table its columns as per Scott in Oracle.
I want to show all columns in a single column named 'statement' like below.

ex-FORD IS A ANALYST AND HIS MANAGER IS JONES HAVING SALARY 3000 FROM DEPARTMENT  RESEARCH

KING IS A PRESIDENT AND HIS MANAGER IS NONE HAVING SALARY 5000 FROM DEPARTMENT ACCOUNTING

Comment: Re-read your question and please tidy it up - put some structure to it and give a clear definition of the table you reference.

Comment: Tables referenced are EMP and DEPT from the Scott example oracle database: http://apexplained.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/the-emp-and-dept-tables-in-oracle/

Comment: is this another homework?

Comment: I put an update in my answer for your nullable manager (based on Dan's query). I like NVL (or COALESCE) better than CASE WHEN IS NULL and you would need a left join instead of an inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.ENAME||' is a ' || x.JOB||' and his manager is '||y.ENAME||' having salary '||x.sal||' from department '||d.DNAME
FROM EMP x, EMP y, dept d
where x.MGR = y.EMPNO(+)
and x.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
```

Comment: its close but i want   'null' in place of KING'S manager

Comment: There is no manager for 'King' so output for that will be "KING is a PRESIDENT and his manager is  having salary 5000 from department ACCOUNTING"

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT emp.ename || ' IS A ' || emp.job || ' AND HIS MANAGER IS ' || mgr.ename || ' HAVING SALARY ' || TO_CHAR(emp.sal) || ' FROM DEPARTMENT ' || dept.dname
FROM emp
INNER JOIN emp AS mgr ON emp.mgr = mgr.empno
INNER JOIN dept ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
```

Comment: Can it be null who do not have manager in the statement?

Comment: Yes, but you could always check that using something like: CASE WHEN mgr.ename IS NULL THEN ' AND HE HAS NO MANAGER ' ELSE ' AND HIS MANAGER IS ' || mgr.ename END

Answer (score 1):

You can combine strings using pipes:

```
SELECT 'COLUMN1' || ' ' || 'COLUMN2'
FROM DUAL
```

**EDIT:**

Update with actual query for nullable manager:

```
 SELECT emp.ename || ' IS A ' || emp.job || ' AND HIS MANAGER IS ' || NVL(mgr.ename, 'NULL') || ' HAVING SALARY ' || TO_CHAR(emp.sal) || ' FROM DEPARTMENT ' || dept.dname
 FROM emp
 LEFT JOIN emp AS mgr ON emp.mgr = mgr.empno
 INNER JOIN dept ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
```